# How to append the values in table using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

Here i am passing javascript varaible into PHP function using AJAX ,here it will be working fine,**  console.log(fname);** Here i got all values but append the tables means i am getting [object Object],how can solve this error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reservation").on("change", function() {
       var reservation = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'date-range.php',
              data: {
                  logindate: reservation,
              },
              success: function( data ) {
              var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
                console.log(res);
                 if(res['status']=="success"){

                  var htmlString='';

                   $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {

                   htmlString+='<tr>';
                   var ssm_id = value.ssm_id; // here i got ssmid
                   htmlString+='<td>'+value.ssm_id+'</td>';
                   htmlString+='<td>'+ $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'config/functions.php',
                   data: {
                        ssm_id: ssm_id,
                    },
                    success: function( fname ) {
                    console.log(fname);//HERE I GOT ALL VALUES
                    htmlString+='<td>'+fname+'</td>';// BUT HERE I CAN'T APPENT THE VALUES IN TABLE 
                     }
                   });+'</td>';
                   htmlString+='<td>'+'Muthuraja'+'</td>';
                   htmlString+='<td>'+'20-05-2016'+'</td>';
                   htmlString+='<td>'+'status'+'</td>';
                   htmlString+='<td>'+value.source+'</td>';
                   htmlString+='<td>'+ "<span style='color:green'>View Profile</span>"+'</td>';


                  /* htmlString+='<td>'+ "<span style='color:green'>Completed</span>"+'</td>';*/

                   htmlString+='</tr>';
                    });
                   $('#datatable-editable > tbody').empty().append(htmlString);
                 }
                 else{
                  $('#datatable-editable > tbody').empty().append("<center style='height:100px;padding-top:36px;color:red;font-size:17px;'><b>No matching records found</b></center>");
                 }
              }
          });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

functions.php

```
<?php

$ssm_id = $_POST['ssm_id'];
if(!empty($ssm_id)){
    echo firstname($ssm_id);
}

function firstname($id)
{
    $f="SELECT firstname FROM register WHERE matri_id='$id'";
    $rr=mysql_query($f);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rr)) {
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    }
    return $firstname;
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the response type in AJAX call?? Is it just a String or `JSON`??

Comment: Can we see the datas pls ?

Comment: console.log(fname);//HERE I GOT ALL VALUES => Can you put what it output pls ?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(data);` and add the result to your question

Comment: you should use promise. Execute the first request then the second one and finally build your table. By the way you shoul use a template framework like Handlebars.js instead of using htmlString+='...'

Comment: console.log(data);//Here i got string like,Kani,mahi,banu like that

Comment: So you had better show us the PHP code that created this response, as it does not look like what you are attempting to use it as **Add that to your question using the EDIT link**

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I believe its the little bit of PHP at the bottom of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact format of your JSON, it's hard to give a definitive answer. However, assuming you have a JSON array of objects that represent your rows, you'd need to iterate over that array and for each object do the following:

Create a new `<tr>` element - `var $tr = $('<tr/>');`
For each item of information (I assume one item per `<td>`), create a `<td>` element and set its content - `var $td = $('<td/>').html(x.y)` (x is your current object, y is a field in the object) then append it to the row - `$tr.append($td);.`
Append the row before the last row in the existing table - `$('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);`
Following from the additional information provided in the question, the following code should do what you need to do:

```
success: function(result) {
    //result is json format
    var $tr = $('<tr/>');
    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.itemname));
    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.qty));
    $tr.append($('<td/>').html(result.prices));
    $('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);
}
```